# Better DataStructure for passing Dataset from C# application to C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop

What will be the good data structure to pass dataset from C# application to C++ Dll. I could see struct will be good option where I need to write intermediate layer that will assign Dataset data to struct and send it to the C++ DLL. Also if I want to return it from DLL then DLL will send struct data to C# application and C# intermediate layer will assign it to the DataSet.

Please suggest on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Dataset return it as string. Let the string have  XML data. so that XML data can be processed at any language.

Comment: XML data can be one option but then I need to parse it at C# application that I don't want.